# Getting object from wcfwebservice to Android phone

Tags: android, web-services, wcf

I want to send name and password to wcf webservice and get a result of "User" object. I tried this way but I can't success. How can I get it? I can get easily "string" and "integer" values from webservice.
-Android-

```
        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE,METHODNAME);
        request.addProperty("pname",this.pName);
        request.addProperty("pass",this.pass);

        SoapSerializationEnvelope sp = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        sp.dotNet = true; 
        sp.setOutputSoapObject(request); 
        try {   
            HttpTransportSE aht = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
            aht.call(SOAPACTION,sp);
            SoapObject resultstring = (SoapObject)sp.getResponse();

            //I don'T know here is true or not? In here, I want to get object as a  result

            this.pID = Integer.parseInt(resultstring.getProperty(0).toString());
            this.uID = Integer.parseInt(resultstring.getProperty(1).toString());
            this.birthDate  = Date.valueOf(resultstring.getProperty(2).toString());
            this.email  = resultstring.getProperty(3).toString();


            return true;
```

WCF Web Service

```
   public Patients PatientLogin(string pname, string pass)
    {

        var patient = db.Patients.SingleOrDefault(x => x.pName.Equals(pname) && PassEncryption.EqualPass(x.pass,pass));

        if (patient != null)
        {
            return patient;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: check in google there is a lot examples

Comment: Try to do your wcf restful. Then things are much more simple. You do not need to use soap. Just httppost and httpget.

Comment: Which java lib you are using for soap? I have used ksoap2. But generally as you create the service use rest.

Comment: I'm using Ksoap2. How restful? I shouldn't send "patients" from wcf?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can get the serialized User object (xml/json), and then parse it.